# chamar função php no c#

Tags: php, c#, funções

Como pelo c# em WindowsFormsApplication chamar uma função de uma página php e pegar o valor dela, exemplo:
página php:

```
function retornar()
{
  $valor = "aa";
  return $valor;
}
```

No caso eu gostaria de chamar essa página pelo c# e atribuir a uma variável do c# o valor que virá, no caso "aa".

Comment: O código php é seu? pode alterar ele?

Comment: Sim , posso, é meu

Comment: Sim é possível! você precisa fazer uma request com o C# e no código php deve fazer um `echo`  com o formato desejado seja um json ou texto puro, aí só pegar a response.

Comment: tem algum link de exemplo de request para eu ler? por favor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se é uma "página php" então suponho que esteja falando de uma página web mesmo, então na pratica você deve chamar a função na sua página web, por exemplo `teste.php`:

```
<?php

function retornar() {
  $valor = "aa";
  return $valor;
}

echo retornar();
```

Ou pode até mesmo ser isto apenas:

```
<?php

echo "aa";
```

E depois chame o endereço `http://seusite/teste.php` (seusite é apenas um exemplo) no **seu próprio c#**, você pode usar [*WebClient*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Chame no seu arquivo C#

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://seusite/teste.php");
```

Ou salvar o conteúdo em um documento:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
client.DownloadFile("http://seusite/teste.php", " C:\conteudo.txt");
```

Comment: ai no caso pra eu "acessar" a função retornar eu precisaria colocar no link? fiquei com dúvida nisso, se puder me explicar

Comment: Sim, precisa do link @rods, mas tem como fazer um bind se o script php estiver na mesma máquina que o script c#. Mas se o .php for uma página web mesmo, da forma que citei funciona. O `WebClient` deve estar no seu C#

Comment: eu coloco como no link então para chegar até a função "retornar" tomando como exemplo que a pagina se chame teste.php e seja daque link que você mostrou

Comment: @rods na verdade você chama o retornar na página PHP, para o C# isto é irrelevante, já que o download é feito depois de processado, o `<?php echo retornar();`, foi só um exemplo, você pode fazer assim `<?php echo 'rods';` que vai chegar assim `rods` no C# depois do `DownloadString` ;)

Comment: ahhh, eu faço o download do arquivo todo e pego qual parte eu quero no caso pelo proprio c#?

Comment: Isso mesmo @rods ;)

Comment: Valeuzão não tinha entendido

Comment: MUITO obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o que pesquisei, em C# você pode executar o que quiser na linha comando da seguinte maneira:

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText= "/C copy /b Image1.jpg + Archive.rar Image2.jpg";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands

Uma vez que você pode executar comandos no PC, ao invés de acessar uma URL você pode executar o código PHP através do interpretador que vem junto do PHP5+. Seria apenas o caso de você executar o seu arquivo .php direto da linha de comando, daí não vai precisar de um servidor rodando o programa desejado. Você pode, inclusive, passar argumentos direto nessa linha de comando, e fazer referência lá dentro do PHP através dos objetos $argc (quantidade de argumentos) e $argv (os argumentos em si, em string).

```
php nome_do_arquivo.php argumento1 argumento2
```